# Registered Trademark on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, symbols

I want to display registered trademark (i.e 'R' inside circle) on jsp page, I found using `&#174;` html code. I can display it but in my case I want to display it by using iterator in jsp which is (the iterator) fetching the data from DB in its action class and displaying it on jsp (I saved this symbol into a table of DB) as we do this always and for this symbol I have inserted the same html code (`&#174;`) in DB but its displaying `&#174;` code itself in jsp.
Please let me know if you have any idea.

I'm using:**<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>** for jsp.Since I did googling to find this solution and found its something dependent on above things too but it is already correct (as much I know).

below is the jsp sample code:

```
<s:iterator value="options" status="rowstatus">
<!-- Option rows -->
<tr>
<td>
<s:property value="name"/>
</td>
<td class="clsQuestions2"><s:property value="value"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

if I'm putting code that if `&#174;` comes then print it `&#174;` itself then it displaying the registered trade mark but I dont want it. for example in below case its displaying the symbol:

```
<s:if test="name == 'virtuwell&#174;'">virtuwell®</s:if>
```

Comment: what is the tag library `s`? have you confirmed that ® really exists in the DB as such and not as &#174;?

Comment: 'S' is taglib for struts, I have added it by using :<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%> and below solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 property tag provides HTML-escaping.
Try this to avoid it:

```
<s:property value="name" escape="false" />
```